# Обособление оборота с "хоть"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Постепенно Мухтар привыкает к его проводнику Глазычеву и, хоть с проблемами, но оканчивает обучение.*

Перед "хоть" запятая действительно нужна? Ведь если выключить обособленную часть, теряется смысл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Постепенно Мухтар привыкает к своему проводнику Глазычеву и хоть с проблемами, но оканчивает обучение.**

Из справочника "Трудные случаи пунктуации":

Конструкция с двойным союзом **ХОТЬ/ХОТЯ(И)...НО, А, ДА**. Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза.

Да, он все знает, все понимает и этими словами говорит мне, что **хотя и стыдно, а надо пережить свой стыд** (Л. Толстой).

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, надо поправить Википедию. :)

Comment: Мне тоже казалось, что она лишняя, но в Нацкорпусе я почему-то нашёл аналогичные запятые перед "хоть". Выходит, там тоже неверно.